# SSH check success but still can not clone the git repo

Tags: git, ssh

In my Mac I have generated the ssh-key in my `~/.ssh` directory.

and I also copied the `id_rsa.pub`'s public key to my GitHub account settings SSH Keys.

but I can not clone from the GitHub, says:

```
$ sudo git clone git@github.com:WHMCS/templates-six.git whmcs_six_template
Cloning into 'whmcs_six_template'...
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Then I searched the google find a way to check SSH connect:

```
$ ssh -T git@github.com
Hi sof-3! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

You see this check success, why I get error when clone the git repo?

Answer (score 1):

You should use your current account for git clone:

```
$ git clone git@github.com:WHMCS/templates-six.git whmcs_six_template
```

because this `id_rsa.pub` is under your current user `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`, if you use `root` user for clone it will use root user's `.ssh` directory for search your private secret key.